# Get list accounts etherjs is empty array when f5 refresh page

Tags: javascript, blockchain, metamask, coinbase-api, ethers.js

I have both meta mask and coin base. My code:

`const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);`

`const accounts = await provider.listAccounts();`

accounts = [] when i f5 refresh page. My d-app had connected to metamask and coin base is not. Any way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

you should first enable the connection between your site and metamask
you can go to your metamask and click on connected sites on the 3 dots and add your site manually or write `await window.ethereum.enable` in your code.